# Merge two tables column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel file like:
[image: this]

This is just a small part of the whole file.

I want to merge columns so that I get somthing like:
{[image: this]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZFAT.png).

I am not fimiliar with excel key words and I am not influent in english so I could not find proper solution in google.

Any solution would be appericiated.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Comment: If not too many columns, then it's easy to just insert new columns between 1&2, 2&3, etc... and then copy your lower data from 1 into the top of new column 2, etc.

Comment: Copy and paste??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=INDEX(  (A1:A3,A5:A7,C1:C3,C5:C7,E1:E3,E5:E7),  ROW(1:3),  ,  {1,2,3,4,5,6})
```

or the more modern:

```
=INDEX(  (A1:A3,A5:A7,C1:C3,C5:C7,E1:E3,E5:E7),  SEQUENCE(3),  ,  SEQUENCE(1,6))
```

It use `INDEX()`, in particular its last parameter (the fourth one no one much uses):  the "Areas" parameter along with a couple ways to specify arrays of values for the rows and for the areas to include (first one above), or the more modern second one which only needs `SEQUENCE()`.

Often a function will refuse to take more than one use of `SEQUENCE()` so that even it must be combined with using one of the older techniques for other parameters in the function. `INDEX()` will take more than one use of `SEQUENCE()`, so specifying things, especially if you desire them to be in reverse order, is much easier than with the older techniques. Not that they are beastly or hard to implement, they just aren't as directly on point so harder to understand a year later.

Naturally, for either formula, you would generate the important value in the method chosen for creating a parameter's internal array constant in a more complex way than simply typing a number or two... if your need here is ongoing. (If not ongoing, simply seeing what the numbers need to be is no difficulty.)

So instead of the simple `ROW(1:3)` shown, you might end up with something like `ROW("1:"&INDIRECT(ROWS(A1:A3)))` — whatever your specific situation requires.

Anyway, if you use an array constant, literally typed ("hardcoded") in the formula or generated by Excel while calculating the formula (what I called an "internal array constant" earlier), for any of the parameters, you can't just put commas and no values for both of the other two parameters to get all of the rows in an area, nor can you use the "comma-0" technique. You actually have to specify completely at least one of the parameters, rows or columns desired, whether you like it or not. But not both... the other can be left blank.

Another oddity is in the second formula's second use of `SEQUENCE()`. You might think that it would need something other than that "1" for its rows parameter, in fact, that it ought to be the total number of rows in the areas. But no. That array being formed refers to the actual areas themselves, not the rows and columns in them. So you use just a simple "1" for it.

To specify the areas, you need to place them all inside a set of parentheses:  `()`. If not, Excel thinks they are parameters, not areas.

If you specify them in some order other than the order you need to output them, for any of many good reasons, you can take them in the order needed by specifying an exact, literal array constant for the Areas parameter that is not just the 1-6 I show. For instance, to get the column A areas 3rd and 4th not 1st and 2nd, you'd do this:  `{3,4,1,2,5,6}`. See how they are now the 3rd and 4th areas being selected?

And if you need empty columns between them, you'd just need to include some areas in some out-of-the-way place on the worksheet that will always be empty so what's inserted is empty material so it looks like blank columns are in between the data columns — if you also format to not display 0's in those output columns. Or specify cells with the value `""` so the output cells look empty with default formatting. Lots of tricks like that are available.